# get all button elements dragged into div element

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

im trying to make any button elements can be dragged into a div. in the end i want to make sure that any new button i made can be dragged into a div. i tried using `querySelectorAll` to grab any element, but it doesn't work like expected. right now only one button can be dragged into a div. here is the code

```js
let button = document.querySelector('button')
let div = document.querySelector('div')

// for button
button.addEventListener('dragstart', function (ev) {
  let lol = ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", 'button');
  console.log(lol)
})


// for div
div.addEventListener('dragover', function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault()
})
div.addEventListener('drop', function (ev) {
  ev.preventDefault()
  ev.target.appendChild(document.querySelector('button'));
})
```

```css
#div1 {
    width: 350px;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 3px solid #fff555;
}
```

```html
  <div id="div1"></div><br>
    <button draggable="true">button one</button>
    <button draggable="true">button two</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need use `querySelectorAll`, and use `forEach` on the returned `NodeList` to attach the event handler to each button.

`dataTransfer` is then set with the appropriate `id`, which need to be added in the HTML.

This property is then read back in the `drop` event handler.

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button')
let div = document.querySelector('div')

// for button
buttons.forEach(button=>button.addEventListener('dragstart', function (ev) {
  let lol = ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
  console.log(ev.target.id);
}));


// for div
div.addEventListener('dragover', function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault()
})
div.addEventListener('drop', function (ev) {
  ev.preventDefault()
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(ev.dataTransfer.getData("text")));
})
```

```css
#div1 {
    width: 350px;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 3px solid #fff555;
}
```

```html
  <div id="div1"></div><br>
    <button id='b1' draggable="true">button one</button>
    <button id='b2' draggable="true">button two</button>
```